# PLPGSQL: Passing an argument into a function breaks my quotation marks

Tags: plpgsql

Without functions, I can do:

```
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE something='hello'
```

And my rows with the value of something='hello' get deleted, but as soon I implement functions, I begin to have problems with quotation marks.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION somefunc(varchar)
RETURNS varchar AS $$
BEGIN

  DELETE FROM table1
  WHERE something='$1';

  DELETE FROM table2
  WHERE something='$1';

  RETURN $1;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;`
```

Nothing seems to work. I have tried (all variations that I saw on SO or elsewhere):

```
something=$1   <-- says column "hello" doesn't exist (because no quotes are given)
something=''$1''
something='''$1'''
something=''''$1''''
something='''||$1||'''
something=$Q$$1$Q1$   <--- gives syntax error
something=$Q1$ $1 $Q1$
something=$$ $1 $$
something=quote_literal($1)
```

And many other variations. How do I get around this??

Btw, I am using a python script to run the function. Here's the line that runs it. I've also tried adding quotes into this line as well to no avail:

```
cur.execute("SELECT somefunc(%s);" % (sys.argv[2]))
```

Thank you!

Comment: Using `DELETE FROM table1 WHERE something=$1;` and  `SELECT somefunc('hello')` works for me. So I guess it must have something to do with how you call the function from python (I don't know Python, so I have no idea what it could be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is based on the implicit use of prepare statements. When prepared statements are used, query and parameters are passed to the database server separately. Do not quote values in that scenario.
PL/pgSQL uses prepared statements, psycopg2 uses prepared statements, too:

```
...
DECLARE myvar int;
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM mytab WHERE column = myvar; -- quietly using prepared statement
```

versus

```
DECLARE myvar int;
BEGIN
   -- using dynamic SQL is similar to classic languages, quoting is necessary
   -- but use the quote_literal() function to protect against SQL injection
   EXECUTE 'DELETE FROM mytab WHERE column = ' || quote_literal(myvar);

   -- or dynamic SQL with "USING" clause 
   EXECUTE 'DELETE FROM mytab WHERE column = $1' USING myvar;
```

Comment: Even my implementation works when I use ints... it only stops working when I use varchars. I had the same problems, even with the implementation you suggested. I will mark your answer as correct for the time you spent on it, though. Thank you!

Comment: @Ronny: Your example in the question can never work correctly - neither for `integer` nor for `varchar`.